# how can implement crunch wordlist generator

Tags: python

This is what I wrote...

```
def brute(m,pattern=None):
    letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    spec = '#@&$%*()+'
    upper = letters.upper()
    number = '1234567890'
    info = {'@':spec,'^':upper,'%':letters,'*':number}
    chars = [info.get(p,letters) for _,p in zip(range(m),pattern or  letters)]
    def inner(m):
        if m:
            for l in chars[~m]:
                for j in inner(m-1):
                    yield(l+j)
        else:
            for l in chars[~m]:
                yield l
    for i in inner(m-1):
        print(i)
```

I want to know how to write a tool similar to crunch in kali...

I would be grateful if you could implement it in Python.

And why is my code so slow even when I write the output to file??
How to make it faster??

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? It isn't obvious. Is this your attempt to make something like crunch in kali? For those who have never heard of that, could you please describe it?

Comment: Creating a wordlist according to the string length and pattern
For example, brute(6,'@%%*@^')

Words with length 6.@john Coleman

Comment: Using `itertools.product` would be more efficient than what you are doing.

Comment: i I am learning Python
And I just want to know how a tool like crunch works or how to make it faster ,sir.. @john Coleman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an itertools based approach which might do what you want:

```
import itertools, string

def brute(m,pattern=None):
    if pattern is None:
        pattern = '%'*m
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    spec = '#@&$%*()+'
    number = '1234567890'
    info = {'@':spec,'^':upper,'%':letters,'*':number}
    chars = [info.get(d,letters) for d in pattern]
    return [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(*chars)]
```

For example, `words = brute(6,'@%%*@^')` takes about 2 seconds to evaluate to a list of `14236560` words.

Comment: thank you sir
crunch can print  wordlists with 20 length and with  great speed...

 Can you explain how it does this?

Comment: @Warrior199 A word is essentially a product where each factor is drawn from an alphabet. The pattern controls what alphabet is used in what position. Itertools is a very efficient library for such things. See this for details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html